# flutter listTile with a long text for the Title

Tags: flutter

I have a  listTile  title with a long text .

I whoud like the title to show as must text as possible , in one single line ...

If I use softWrap: true,   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, the text is cut after 4 caracter´s

like : exampl....

if I don´t use  softWrap: true,   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, the text is shown in 3 or 4 lines

I tryied using FittedBox , but the text get´s really small .. unreadable ....

Any ideias how to get this ?

title: Text(
inc.descricao,
style: TextStyle(
color: Colors.white,
fontFamily: "Roboto",
fontSize: 16,
),

```
   softWrap: true,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  ),
```

thank You Roque

Answer (score 0):

Use layout Flexible/Container with text overflow:

```
Flexible(
  child: Container(
    child: Text(
      'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa',
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 13.0,),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: thank you .. din´t work ...      The ParentDataWidget Flexible(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData.

Usually, this means that the Flexible widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Flexible widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Flexible is currently placed inside a _ListTile widget.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` should work.
My guess is Text widget container making the Text widget shorter

Try wrapping Text widget in Container with maximum width

```
      Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Text(
          'reaaaaaly long text, like reaaaaaaaaaaaaaly long',
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
```

Comment: thank you are rigth , i had a test text like "ads1 gsdagjdashjhgdasjhgdasjhdgsajhdgjasddjhdfas"

Comment: thank you are rigth , i had a test text like "ads1 gsdagjdashjhgdasjhgdasjhdgsajhdgjasddjhdfas" ... and the text was cut at first for word  (ads1 ) , when I insert spaces in the big "word"  it worked as i wanted  ..
  
  it seems that the problem after all was between the screen and the chair (me) ... Thank you ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use text property Overflow.elipsis.

```
              ListTile(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                
              minLeadingWidth: 0,
                                title: Text(
                "Hello Overflow",
             
             
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Open Sans',
                  fontSize: 15,
                  color: Color(0xff23233c),
                  letterSpacing: -0.44999999999999996,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
                softWrap: true,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            )
```